# What will happen, if Model::$id will not be cleared by create()?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

On CakePHPs blog tutorial there will be a post saved by following action:

```
public function add() 
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) 
    {
        $this->Post->create();
        if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) 
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your post.'));
    }
}
```

I not really understand the purpose of `$this->Post->create();` described in Cookbook:

> [...]it resets the model state for saving new information. It does not
>   actually create a record in the database but clears Model::$id  [...]

(Found at [Cookbook 2.x](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html))

What will happen, if Model::$id will not be cleared by `create();`?

Comment: I don't understand the question `What will happen, if Model::$id will not be cleared by create();?` - are you asking if it _will_ be cleared? (yes, it will)

Comment: @AD78six: Thank you for your comment. When I delete the row  `$this->Post->create();` my post will be saved just as well. So why should´nt I leave it out?

Comment: it simply ensures the model is in a clean state. You _can_ leave it out it's a good habit to keep it though.

Comment: @AD7six: That you have to clean the model in certain cases, I can imagine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question to (now) mean:

> Can I leave out the create call in this code example:

### Yes, yes you can

[Model::create](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-create-array-data-array) resets the model to a consistent state, deleting the data property and resetting the id to null.

This method only does something/anything if the model has been modified; if the model state hasn't been modified, or it's the first called method of an action it won't do anything - but it's a good habit to always call `create` whenever the existing model state is not relevant to the next model method call, and can prevent unexpected application bugs.

Comment: Very nice - makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As per the code you provided in you question, you can remove Model::create(). It won't effect data insertion.

But it is important to clear Model::$id, when you are inserting records in loop. Because if you don't, only one record will be inserted and will overwritten with next records.

For example,

```
$posts = array(
    0 => array(
        'title' => "Title one"
    ),
    1 => array(
        'title' => "Title two"
    ),
    2 => array(
        'title' => "Title three"
    )
);

foreach($posts as $post) {
    $this->Post->create(); // Or you can use $this->Post->id = null;
    $this->Post->save($post);
}
```

If you remove $this->Post->create(), on first execution it will insert a new record with title "Title one", and sets last insert id as Model::$id, say for example 21. On second execution, because we have not cleared the Model::$id, it will update the record with the title "Title two" instead of inserting it as a new record, and so on.
At last, you will get only one record with id 21, and it's title value will be "Title three".

This is just an example, there are other ways available to save multiple records without loop.

Hope this will help.